# offset().top для inline-block

Tags: html, jquery, css

[ССЫЛКА НА CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/KNooaZ?editors=0110)

Есть такая структура (`li:inline-block;` при ресайзе перестраиваются друг под друга):

```js
$('.on').click(function(){
  var that = $(this),
    item = $('.item'),
    itemNum = that.data('item');
  
  console.log(item.offset().top+ item.outerHeight(true));
  
  item.filter('.item__'+itemNum).css({
   'top': item.offset().top+ item.outerHeight(true) - $(window).scrollTop()
  });

  item.filter('.item__'+itemNum)
    .addClass('open')
    .siblings()
    .removeClass('open');
  
  
  $(window).resize(function() {
       console.log(item.offset().top+ item.outerHeight(true));
    
   item.filter('.item_'+itemNum).css({
    'top': item.offset().top+ item.outerHeight(true) - $(window).scrollTop()
   });
  });  
});
```

```css
i {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  
  display: none;
}

.item.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
  <li class="on" data-item = "item-1"><i></i></li>
  <li class="on" data-item = "item-2"><i></i></li>
  <li class="on" data-item = "item-3"><i></i></li>
  <li class="on" data-item = "item-4"><i></i></li>
  <li class="on" data-item = "item-5"><i></i></li>
</ul>
  
  <ul>
    <li class="item item__item-1">
      <span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы соответствующие лишкам блоки `item__item-1\2\3`... принимали соответствующее  положение `top` li.on height (блок под лишкой).

В моем рабочем варианте, почему-то offset().top какие-то непонятные значения и всегда разные выдает. Если использовать position: fixed то все отлично, но как абсолют так все ломается!

Может быть кто-то подскажет что не так в коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог `position.top()`:

```js
$('.on').click(function(){
  var that = $(this),
    item = $('.item'),
    itemNum = that.data('item');
  
  
  console.log(that.position().top +' ' + that.outerHeight(true))
  
  item.filter('.item__'+itemNum).css({
    'top': that.position().top + that.outerHeight(true)
  });

  item.filter('.item__'+itemNum)
    .addClass('open')
    .siblings()
    .removeClass('open');
  
  
  $(window).resize(function() {      
    
    item.filter('.item_'+itemNum).css({
      'top': that.position().top + that.outerHeight(true)
    });
  });  
});
```

```css
i {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  
  display: none;
}

.item.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
  <li class="on" data-item = "item-1"><i></i></li>
  <li class="on" data-item = "item-2"><i></i></li>
  <li class="on" data-item = "item-3"><i></i></li>
  <li class="on" data-item = "item-4"><i></i></li>
  <li class="on" data-item = "item-5"><i></i></li>
</ul>
  
  <ul>
    <li class="item item__item-1">
      <span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="item item__item-2">
      <span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="item item__item-3">
      <span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="item item__item-4">
      <span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="item item__item-5">
      <span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```